# Owasp Zap generate report error in azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, owasp, zap

We have a azure pipeline which runs weekly and executes owasp zap. Up until about 6 weeks about this job ran without issue but recently we are getting errors on the Geneate Report step and I cannot figure out why. Nothing has changed on our side so I am thinking this is something to do with Azure.
Anyway these are the steps

```
   steps:
    - task: DockerInstaller@0
      displayName: 'Install Docker'
      condition: always()
    
    - bash: |
          mkdir wrk
          chmod 777 wrk
          docker run \
          --volume $(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)/wrk:/output:rw \
          --volume $(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)/wrk:/zap/wrk:rw \
          registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/dast:latest /analyze -t ${target} \
          --full-scan False \
          -r report.html \
          -x report.xml
       
      displayName: 'Run ZAP scan'
      continueOnError: true
      env:
        target: https://www.abcxyz.com
    
    - bash: 'wget -O OWASPToNUnit3.xslt https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sudhinsr/6dad07c20785d8d00ffd406a6c581b15/raw/42b2fe2201f6f054b97673239970e4d6eca2e308/OWASPToNUnit3.xslt'
      displayName: 'Download OWASPToNUnit3'
      continueOnError: true
        
    - bash: |
          wget https://www.saxonica.com/download/SaxonHE11-5J.zip
          unzip SaxonHE11-5J.zip
      displayName: 'Download Saxon'
      continueOnError: true
    
    - bash: |
       java -jar saxon-he-11.5.jar -xsl:$(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)/OWASPToNUnit3.xslt -s:$(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)/wrk/report.xml -o:$(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)/testReport.xml
       
      displayName: 'Generate Report'
      continueOnError: true
    
    - task: PublishTestResults@2
      displayName: 'Publish Pi Test Results'
      inputs:
        testResultsFormat: NUnit
        testResultsFiles: testReport.xml
        searchFolder: '$(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)'
      continueOnError: true
```

Everything appears fine until here

[image]

And when I log at the log you can see the report is not being created or does not exist

```
2023-06-13T14:52:50.6301926Z ##[section]Starting: Generate Report
2023-06-13T14:52:50.6305291Z ==============================================================================
2023-06-13T14:52:50.6305382Z Task         : Bash
2023-06-13T14:52:50.6305424Z Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
2023-06-13T14:52:50.6305494Z Version      : 3.214.0
2023-06-13T14:52:50.6305539Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-06-13T14:52:50.6305590Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
2023-06-13T14:52:50.6305676Z ==============================================================================
2023-06-13T14:52:50.7394911Z Generating script.
2023-06-13T14:52:50.7408248Z Script contents:
2023-06-13T14:52:50.7409109Z java -jar saxon-he-11.5.jar -xsl:/home/vsts/work/r1/a/OWASPToNUnit3.xslt -s:/home/vsts/work/r1/a/wrk/report.xml -o:/home/vsts/work/r1/a/testReport.xml
2023-06-13T14:52:50.7418064Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2023-06-13T14:52:50.7428255Z [command]/usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/8e936c3d-9c88-4700-9b19-bede87942d5b.sh
2023-06-13T14:52:51.3252644Z Source file /home/vsts/work/r1/a/wrk/report.xml does not exist
2023-06-13T14:52:51.3353558Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '2'.
2023-06-13T14:52:51.3368023Z ##[warning]RetryHelper encountered task failure, will retry (attempt #: 1 out of 2) after 1000 ms
2023-06-13T14:52:52.4318153Z Generating script.
2023-06-13T14:52:52.4334398Z Script contents:
2023-06-13T14:52:52.4336037Z java -jar saxon-he-11.5.jar -xsl:/home/vsts/work/r1/a/OWASPToNUnit3.xslt -s:/home/vsts/work/r1/a/wrk/report.xml -o:/home/vsts/work/r1/a/testReport.xml
2023-06-13T14:52:52.4348418Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2023-06-13T14:52:52.4357462Z [command]/usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/85785ffa-92cb-4954-bdd5-1f6074fd8d35.sh
2023-06-13T14:52:52.8587611Z Source file /home/vsts/work/r1/a/wrk/report.xml does not exist
2023-06-13T14:52:52.8688921Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '2'.
2023-06-13T14:52:52.8760982Z ##[warning]RetryHelper encountered task failure, will retry (attempt #: 2 out of 2) after 4000 ms
2023-06-13T14:52:56.9664077Z Generating script.
2023-06-13T14:52:56.9677388Z Script contents:
2023-06-13T14:52:56.9678043Z java -jar saxon-he-11.5.jar -xsl:/home/vsts/work/r1/a/OWASPToNUnit3.xslt -s:/home/vsts/work/r1/a/wrk/report.xml -o:/home/vsts/work/r1/a/testReport.xml
2023-06-13T14:52:56.9686945Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2023-06-13T14:52:56.9697289Z [command]/usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/4e9abd9b-d959-406e-b1e9-805f7b160469.sh
2023-06-13T14:52:57.4142049Z Source file /home/vsts/work/r1/a/wrk/report.xml does not exist
2023-06-13T14:52:57.4216908Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '2'.
2023-06-13T14:52:57.4252831Z ##[section]Finishing: Generate Report
```

As I have said this was working fine until a couple of weeks ago, can anyone shed any light on what is going on please?

Thanks in advance folks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is down to the Deprecate of DAST_HTML_REPORT, DAST_XML_REPORT, and DAST_MARKDOWN_REPORT for DAST

More info at
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/384340/?_gl=1*16oaarv*_ga*MzQ1NjE3NjEuMTY4Nzc3NDE0OQ..*_ga_ENFH3X7M5Y*MTY4Nzc3NDE0OC4xLjEuMTY4Nzc3NDE1MC4wLjAuMA..

Answer (score 1):

> java -jar saxon-he-11.5.jar -xsl:/home/vsts/work/r1/a/OWASPToNUnit3.xslt -s:/home/vsts/work/r1/a/wrk/report.xml -o:/home/vsts/work/r1/a/testReport.xml

Has nothing to do with ZAP. That's all your customization, whatever you're doing there is failing. Either something isn't readable or writable. (Or the process requires an exclusive lock and the previous file access hasn't finished?)

Comment: I know that, the issue is that the report is no longer being found or is nort being created. TheZAP part is working fine hence my comment 'has this anything to do with azure'